# Data of which exactly point of time did I get when query from oracle or mysql?

Tags: mysql, oracle

For example, a query cost 1 seconds, and during this 1 second, some data updated. Can the query get this update?

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_01555_snapshot_old.htm

Comment: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f%3Fp%3D100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:249455000346146138

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Oracle, in a multi-user environment: when you run a SELECT statement, you'll get data since the last COMMIT performed by any user. For a simple example, if there's two of you, and both of you connect to the database at the same time. Your colleague performs some updates, deletes, inserts, but doesn't commit. When you run your SELECT statement, you'll see data as it was at the moment you connected to the database because anything he did wasn't committed. However, once he commits, your next SELECT will now see modified data.

So, the answer to your question "can the query get this update" is "it depends" on whether those updates were committed or not.